# How do I receive UDP unicast messages as a multicast server using C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, multicast

I am trying to build a system, where the server is multicasting to all clients, and the clients can send messages to the server. As it is now, the server is able to multicast transmit to the clients, but not the other way around. What am I missing?

The server looks like this:

```
    InternetServer::InternetServer(uint16_t port)
{
    int status = 0;
    int enable = 1;
    int disable = 0;

    mainSocket = ::socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);
    if (mainSocket == ERROR_CODE)
        std::cout <<  "Error creating socket." << std::endl; 

    if (::setsockopt(mainSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(enable)) == ERROR_CODE)
        std::cout <<  "System failed to set reuse address." << std::endl;
    if (::setsockopt(mainSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &enable, sizeof(enable)) == ERROR_CODE)
        std::cout <<  "System failed to set reuse port." << std::endl;

    rxaddress = getInternetAddress(INADDR_ANY, port);

    status = ::bind(mainSocket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&rxaddress), sizeof(sockaddr_in));
    if (status == ERROR_CODE)
        std::cout <<  "Error binding socket." << std::endl;
}}
```

And the client looks like this:

```
    InternetClient::InternetClient(uint32_t serverip, uint16_t port)
{
    int status = 0;
    int enable = 1;
    int disable = 0;

    mainSocket = ::socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);
    if (mainSocket == ERROR_CODE)
        std::cout <<  "Error creating socket." << std::endl; 

    if (::setsockopt(mainSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(enable)) == ERROR_CODE)
        std::cout <<  "System failed to set reuse address." << std::endl;
    if (::setsockopt(mainSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &enable, sizeof(enable)) == ERROR_CODE)
        std::cout <<  "System failed to set reuse port." << std::endl;

    status = setsockopt(mainSocket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, &disable, sizeof(disable));
    if (status == ERROR_CODE)
        std::cout <<  "Unable to disable multicast loopback." << std::endl;

    txaddress = getInternetAddress(serverip, port);
}
```

I write using sendto() and receive using recvfrom(). And the address is calculated as

```
struct sockaddr_in SocketSystem::getInternetAddress(uint32_t ip, uint16_t port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    addressLength = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
    memset(&address, 0, addressLength);

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if (ip == INADDR_BROADCAST)
        address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);
    else
    if (ip == INADDR_ANY)
        address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    else
        address.sin_addr.s_addr = ip;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);

    name += address.sin_addr.s_addr;

    return address;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: please show a [mre]. I'm not sure that all your multicast code is relevant to your question?

Comment: You are right. I have updated the code.

Comment: still not a [mre]

Comment: Assuming the server isn't calling `connect()` on its UDP socket (it shouldn't), the multicast UDP socket should be able to receive incoming unicast UDP packets.  If it's not receiving them, that could be due to a firewall, or perhaps the clients are sending them to the wrong IP address or port similar.  You might try running Wireshark on your server machine to see if the client's unicast packets are being received by the server's network card, and if so, whether they are being sent to the correct port or not.

Comment: One step further. If I transmit to an address with INADDR_ANY instead of the server ip, then I can read it. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @JakobClausen `INADDR_ANY` represents the IP `0.0.0.0`, you can't send or connect to that IP, only bind/listen on it